# How to get specified column into dynamic variables from array variables PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have a table in MYSQL called `guest`. There are 3 columns in the `guest` table `GuestId`, `Name`, `Phone`. I want to select all records from the `guest` table and put it into array variables, then I just want to get the phone value from array variables using (for) loop. I have tried using (for) loop then inside the loop I use :

```
$phone = $row[phone];
```

but the result I get is just the value phone of the first record. How to make the phone variables take the phone value from each record in every looping?

Thank you.

Comment: In every iteration of the loop, you are replacing the $phone variable. If you want to keep every record, you need to use an array.

Comment: It depends on what you are planning to do with the $phone variable though. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: @Nimeshka Srimal, ya, i want in every iteration of the loop, the phone variables will replaced with the other phone variables on the next record. I have tried using but i just got the result of phone value on the first record only.

Comment: Yes, it will get replaced definitely. What you are planning to do with the $phone variable?

Comment: first you declared array (`$phone = array()`) and then in loop to store phone into array variable (`$phone[]=$row[phone];`) & you should add your code in the question

Comment: @Nimeshka Srimal, so, in every looping , the variable phone that hold phone value will used to be a number that receiving a messages from my website to a several customer.

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed, thankyou for your comment, ill try it.

Comment: Please add your code. That will be helpful to make any suggestions. You can use the $phone to send a message to the number within the loop itself, or you can store the numbers in an array and use it later. It all depends on how you use it, so we cannot help without seeing the code.

Comment: Ive tried add my code but it wont shown, just 1 line of the code that shown, i tried to post the screenshot of the code but it says "minimal 10 reputation to upload image"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$phones = array_column($arr, 'Phone');
```

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT GuestId, Name, Phone FROM guest";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Phone: " . $row["Phone"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```